# Mosquitto TLS over WifiMulti on ESP8266

Tags: wifi, mqtt

With these few lines I am able to attach my certificate, tell it to `WifiClientSecure` the certificate, start the `wifi` as well as the mosquito `pubsubclient`:

```
WiFiClientSecure espClient;
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
  delay(500);
  Serial.print(".");
}

PubSubClient mqtt_client(espClient); 
mqtt_client.setServer(mqtt_server, 8883);
mqtt_client.setCallback(mqtt_callback);
espClient.setCertificate(ca_crt, ca_crt_len);

if (!mqtt_client.connected()) {
  mqtt_reconnect();
}

mqtt_client.loop();
```

With these lines I am able to connect to wifi, depending on which the closest station is:

```
ESP8266WiFiMulti wifiMulti;


wifiMulti.addAP("primary-network-name", "pass-to-primary-network");
wifiMulti.addAP("secondary-network-name", "pass-to-secondary-network");
wifiMulti.addAP("tertiary-network-name", "pass-to-tertiary-network");

wifiMulti.run();
```

How can I combine both? I.e, I am interested in sending data to secure MQTT over a set of possible wifi networks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WiFiMulti has nothing to to with the MQTT and TLS side of things at all.  It only has anything to do with the WiFi.  As such it just replaces the code that directly interfaces with the WiFi.

That is, this code:

```
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
  delay(500);
  Serial.print(".");
}
```

is replaced by this in the global scope:

```
ESP8266WiFiMulti wifiMulti;
```

This in setup():

```
wifiMulti.addAP("primary-network-name", "pass-to-primary-network");
wifiMulti.addAP("secondary-network-name", "pass-to-secondary-network");
wifiMulti.addAP("tertiary-network-name", "pass-to-tertiary-network");
```

and this in `loop()`:

```
wifiMulti.run();
```

All the MQTT side of things remains exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I tell the `wifiMulti` (or anything else in case it is not `wifiMulti`) my certificate? What I mean is the `espClient.setCertificate(ca_crt, ca_crt_len);` line in the question above :-) Or does that part stay as it is?

Comment: You don't tell the WiFi. You tell the client. That's completely separate to the WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up on the answer from @Majenko.

```
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
ESP8266WiFiMulti wifiMulti;
WiFiClientSecure espClient;

#include <PubSubClient.h>
PubSubClient mqtt_client(espClient);

Serial.println("setup_wifi_multi_addAP()");
wifiMulti.addAP("ap1", "pass1");
wifiMulti.addAP("ap2", "pass2");
wifiMulti.addAP("ap3",  "pass3"); 

while (wifiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED)
{
  Serial.print(".");
  delay(500);
}

Serial.printf(" connected to %s\n", WiFi.SSID().c_str());

mqtt_client.setServer(mqtt_server, 8883);
mqtt_client.setCallback(mqtt_callback);
espClient.setCertificate(ca_crt, ca_crt_len);

if (!mqtt_client.connected()) {
  mqtt_reconnect();
}
mqtt_client.loop();


void mqtt_reconnect() {
  Serial.println("mqtt_reconnect()");
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!mqtt_client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    if (mqtt_client.connect("ESP8266mqtt_client-1")) {
      Serial.println("connected");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(mqtt_client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only secure connection without require_certificate in mosquitto configurattion just change 
espClient.setCertificate(ca_crt, ca_crt_len);
to 
espClient.setCACert(ca_crt, ca_crt_len);

setCertiticate is used mainly to mutual authentication.